# How to choose the within factor in Fixed effect model

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, plm

I am doing a fixed effect model to research on support’s effect on reducing number of injured employees. I have a dataset on company level from 2012-2020:

|  | year | average age | total salary | total number of employees | Segment | Industry | Risk Index | support | total number of Injured employees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company A ID | 2012 | 45 | 5 Million | 55 | S | IT | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| company B ID | 2012 | 48 | 40M | 500 | B | Service | 3 | 0 | 20 |

There are approx. 30k companies, and 10 industries. Should I do the **within industry** fixed effect model, or **within company** fixed effect model? And what is the difference in interpretation of results between these two?

Comment: It is not uncommon to use both, company and industry fixed effects.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to ask how would you interpret the difference between within company and within industry results? :)